# Need to create App ID for Microsoft Graph API that works

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently facing an issue when try to authenticate using OAuth 2 it presents with the following error

error = "unauthorized_client";
 "error_description" = "AADSTS70001: Application 'e2a8a297-651e-4dd7-8c1a-00f38e0c3262' is not supported for this API version.

I am planning to use the following endpoints

http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/excel

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can create an app as described here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/platform/rest then select the Files.Read or Files.ReadWrite permission scope as described here: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes.
Finally Excel REST API is currently under the /beta endpoint.